# Is there a way to read IPTC, EXIF or TIFF Metadata in an Image uploaded to Assets?

Tags: assets, image

I'm trying to see if I can get the Date Created on images within an image upload. Not the date the file was created, but the date the picture was taken. If I open an image up in Preview, in the Inspector I can see that the IPTC, EXIF, and TIFF Metadata contains the information I'm looking for. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) that does something like this:

```
$image = new Image();
$image->load('/path/to/image.jpg');
$exif = $image->getExifMetadata();
```

See [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/io/Image) for other methods on the Image class.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot. It's about time I take a stab at a basic plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You could try out my new ["Asset Metadata"](https://github.com/carlcs/craft-assetmetadata) plugin. It makes use of the [getID3](https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3/) PHP library to extract all sort of metadata from your assets.

To make your life a bit easier, I added further beautified metadata properties like a sound file's playtime duration in ISO 8601 date interval format (i.e. `PT1H21M48S`), or a photo's exposure time as a ratio.